# Getting data from a html structure using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html structure that looks like the following:

```
  <div>
    <div questionName="${data.Name}" class="item">
            <div class="left"><input type="checkbox" class="include-checkbox"/></div>
            <div class="center">{data.Name}</div>
            <div class="right"><input class="comment" placeholder="Comment (optional)"/>
    </div>
   ...
</div>
```

With multiple "items" (divs with class="item"). These are generated. Using jQuery, I need to go through those divs, and if the checkbox for that item is checked, add the value from the center div and input value from the right div as a key-value pair to an object (or a JSON string).
So my resulting object should look like this:

```
{
 "an item" : "some comment the user typed in",
 "another item": "some other comment",
 "yet another item" : ""
}
```

the comment is optional, and if the user doesn't fill anything in it should just contain empty string.

I am able to get all the items, because they have the same class, and run a foreach on them:

```
function submitItems() {
    let items = {};
    $('.item').each(function() {
        ?   
    });
}
```

But how do I then access the elements within the item? For example I want to check the status of the checkbox, but when I do `$('.include-checkbox')` it will give me all of them, not just the one that's inside my element. Also the function within the `.each()` construct, seems to have its own scope so the `items` object is not visible.

I have control over how the generated html looks, so I can add classes, ids or other attributes if need be.

Comment: "But how do I then access the elements within the item": jQuery has .children() method

Comment: In the `.each()` callback the "item" `<div>` elements will be referred to by `this`, so you can use `$(this).find(".center")` for example.

Comment: [`.find()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: @Pointy in my opinion find is too heavy, if you need direct children. Else it is good.

Comment: @Andris It's going to be implemented by a `.querySelectorAll()` in most cases, so it'll be perfectly fine. I don't know where people get browser performance ideas from but modern browsers on computers less than 10 years old are extremely fast.

Comment: Yes, fast they are. But if you need to do same logic against 10k child items and many times, some people may feel it. If you know method which performs better, it is better to tell about that. I have seen many shitty codes and one of the things that makes them shitty is performance issues.
Of course on most cases .find() will be ok, but not always

Comment: @Andris - If there are performance issue then deal with them at that time.  This question has nothing to do with performance and there is no reason to even bring it up.  If the OP is sensible enough to ask questions when they have coding issues then they're sensible enough to say *"it's too slow".*   Using `.Find()` is a perfectly good suggestion in response to this question.  Also, look at whether or not someone has enough rep to suggest they know what they're talking about.  I trust Pointy's knowledge and experience.

Comment: @Archer your answer makes me think, that you aren't trying to write code good at first try in your work place, but deal with problems only when they appear, not before... That is bad developer thinking.

Comment: @Andris My comment was intended to help you see things from a different perspective, but I see it's just offended you.  Not my intention and you have my apologies :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method in jQuery.

```
function submitItems() {
    let items = {};
    $('.item').each(function() {
       // check checkbox is checked 
       if($(this).find('.left :checkbox')[0].checked)
          // if checked then get text and input value and set the property
          items[$(this).find('.center').text().trim()] = $(this).find('.right input').val();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function submitItems() {
    var items = {};
    $('.item').each(function (i, e) {

        var name = $("div", e).slice(1).text();
        var comment = $(".comment", $("div", e).slice(2)).first().val();
        var item = { name: comment };
        items[name] = comment;

    });
    var jsonstring=JSON.stringify(items);
    //do something
}
```